# HTML Canvas Images - Drawing multi canvas image in a page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have a problem with canvas.
i can draw a canvas with single image, but i  can't draw each canvas with image separate.
- if data just have one image it's working fine, but data have multiple image it's not working
can you help me ?

```js
<script>
 var h_notepad = 500;
var w_notepad = 737;
var data = [
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_1.png"},
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_2.png"},
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_3.png"},
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_4.png"}
];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();

  canvas.width = w_notepad;
  canvas.height = h_notepad;


  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.width = w_notepad;
  img.height = h_notepad;

  console.log(img);
  img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w_notepad, h_notepad);
  };
  img.src = data[i].dataImageURL;

  $('body').append(canvas); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DRAWING</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you only get the last one. It's a closure problem. When the onload event fires,  `img` and `ctx` only refer to the last ones created. So you draw `data.length` time on the same canvas. To avoid it, use `this` and wrap the canvas creation in the onload handler:  `img.onload = function(){
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  document.body.appendChild(c);
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
  };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you only get the last one. 
It's a closure problem.

When the `load` event fires,  `img` and `ctx` only refer to the last ones created.

So you draw `data.length` time on the same canvas.

To avoid it, you can use `this` and wrap the canvas creation in the onload handler:

```js
var imgs = ['http://lorempixel.com/200/300/', 'http://lorempixel.com/500/300/', 'http://lorempixel.com/200/100/'];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {

  var img = new Image();
  var width = 500;
  var height = 300;

  img.onload = function() {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = width;
    c.height = height;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0, width, height);
  };

  img.src = imgs[i];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `onload` is asynchronous. So all your code runs before any of `onload` functions will be called. That is why your function

```
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w_notepad, h_notepad);
};
```

uses the latest `ctx` and renders all images in this context.

What you can do is cover this asynchronous call with a synchronous function scope:

```
(function(ctx, img, w_notepad, h_notepad) {
  img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w_notepad, h_notepad);
  };
})(ctx, img, w_notepad, h_notepad);
```

This isolates the variables and keeps there values until you receive the image.